# Cannot use image on Crystal Reports picturebox while it's opened on Windows Forms Picturebox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have the following problem: I'm using a network shared folder to store images used on my software. The software saves the image file's path and uses the path to display the images on Windows Forms Pictureboxes and Crystal Reports Pictureboxes (i'm using the graphics local formula). What is happening is that when the image is opened in a form, the reports are unable to access the image.
Has someone faced the same problem?
Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

guys, i think i've figured out the solution:
I was using Image.FromFile to load the file into the form's picture box.
What i did now, is to create a FileStream (File.OpenRead), set the Image property on the picture box and finally close the stream.